# Updating libc6 package to latest version

Tags: linux

I want to install different softwares in linux, but due to not updating libc6 package, it could not install any package or software; instead it give an error.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Hello!
It will help get better answers if you give an example of the error.

Comment: `libc6` *is* your OS (together with the kernel) and can usually not be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the OS that you have installed.

On **Debian**, you can find *.deb* file of the package/software that you want to install and that command:

```
dkpg -i PACKAGENAME
```

it will install(or try) the package/software without dependencies.

On Red-Hat/CentOS, you can find .rpm file of the package/software and use:

```
rpm -i PACKAGENAME
```